Running ublock with puppeteer
I'd like to use ublock (https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) with puppeteer. I start a chromium/chrome browser, but for whatever reason it does not resolve the path to where the manifest.json is.
Code:
const extensionPath = path.resolve("./uBlock/platform/chromium");//path leads to a manifest.json
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
    headless: false,
    args: [
        '--start-maximized',
        `--load-extension=${extensionPath}`, // Load uBlock Origin extension
    ]
});

I have tried to do it manually, when starting the browser, but this doesn't work either. Am I missing anything by any chance?
The steps I took:

git clone the ublock project in my project
the code above
look up a website of which I know serves ads, but I keep getting them




git clone the ublock project in my project
the code above


After step 1., you need to build the extension after cloning it. To build the extension:
make chromium

A working version will become available at ./dist/build/uBlock0.chromium/, this is where the manifest.json file is located.

what you said is correct, but it does not work. I still get ads
